# Typescript compiler doesn't accept cyrillic

Tags: compilation, typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using JetBrains WebStorm and I have that problem.
If i type in the .ts file, for example:

```
var test: string = 'тест';
```

it becomes:

```
var test = 'пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ';
```

Is there a way, to compile the TypeScript files without loosing the non-latin strings.

Comment: Does [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html) help?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript compiler [accept cyrillic just fine](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20test%3A%20string%20%3D%20'%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82'%3B). You should setup your editor to use UTF8 encoding for your files:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

[image]

Comment: It was currently UTF-8. The problem still appears. In the .ts file, when I type the cytillic it's ok, but then in the compile .js file it's with these strange symbols.

Comment: This is per project setting. Check also that your file is in UTF8 encoding - you should see it in the status bar of the PhpStorm (at the bottom of the window). To investigate further, just try to compile your file with `tsc` in your command line